# How to get 'real-time' data from db PyQt4

Tags: python, django, pyqt, pyqt4

Before I start, I must submit that I am just an intermediate Python developer and so I hope I will not receive any backlash for my question.

I'm building a hospital system using Python and PyQt4 for the client side, which communicates with a Django based server through an API. Multiple clients will be communicating with the server. The system is role based and thus the client displays a different interface for each of the roles e.g patient_registration, triage, doctors_desk etc.

The problem i'm struggling with is how to handle the queuing of patients. Each doctor should be able to view the queued patients from his/her desk. In the db, I have a table patient_queue which handles those records. Displaying the info currently in the table is quite straightforward, however, how I'm I supposed to make any new record that is added to  the patient_queue table to appear in the doctors' queue automatically? How can I ensure the doctors have the latest data from the db without having to do something hacky like making the query periodically??

Thank you.

Comment: I have no more experience than you do (probably a lot less), but I think you should consider running another server (besides the Django server), that all the clients will connect to, and instead using the Django API, they will send messages to the server, which in turn will update the database (via the Django api, or directly), and alert the other clients that a change has occured (much like a chat application). if you are not going to use web interface, you might also want to replace the http server (and the http api) with a persistent TCP server such as Twisted.

Comment: I just put up a suggestion that you may want to consider, nothing that can be considered "the right way" to do what you are asking or something...

Comment: Thank you RB14. In case bad comes to worse I'll have to do that. However I'm still hoping there's a simpler solution.

Comment: I think running a separate Tornado server to enable long-polling the particular model will suffice. But let us wait and see if we will get a better solution.

Comment: I have not used django but it seems to support data pushing to clients (do a search for "django push data"), can you explain why this is not adequate? Like [django-push](https://django-push.readthedocs.org/en/latest/).

Comment: Django itself is not good for that since its ORM is blocking.

Comment: I'm considering using ZeroMQ pub/sub...publishers will publish on saving the record to the db, then the subscribers will be receiving the published data.

Answer (score 1):

you can use pyqt [QSqlTableModel](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qsqltablemodel.html) and it can be used as source to widgets like treeview, tableview.
First create a database connection. eg sqlite:

```
db = QtSql.QSqlDatabase.addDatabase('QSQLITE')
db.setDatabaseName('database_name.db')
model = QtSql.QSqlTableModel()
model.setTable('database_table_name')
model.setEditStrategy(QtSql.QSqlTableModel.OnManualSubmit)
model.select()
```

Here i used tableview. You can use other views such as treeview.

```
self.tableView = QtGui.QTableView()
self.tableView.setModel(self.model)
```

Comment: @JoelC There is not much details with sample code is available on net. You have to refer the [documention](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qsqltablemodel.html). I have added an example in answer. Hope it helps.